# Can a react leak happen in timer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Component can get unmount at any random time, is it possible that somehow both A and B execute leading to a leak?

```
class Watch extends React.Component {
  state = { time: 5 };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.state.time);
      if (this.state.time) this.tick();
      else clearInterval(this.timer);                                 // A
    }, 500);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.state.time) clearInterval(this.timer);                   // B
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ time: prevState.time - 1 }));
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Time:{this.state.time}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if it is a problem if `clearInterval()` gets called twice? It shouldn't be a problem. Are you having some sort of unusual behavior?

Comment: Yes. Just want to know  if componentWillUnmount and setInterval callback can get executed  at same time. Also is there need of try-catch here?

Comment: clearInterval cannot throw, and if the timer id doesn't exist or has already been canceled it simply has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test if state before clearing the interval in componentWillUnmount. You always need to clear the interval on unmount.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
     clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
```

Comment: Want to know if in any scenario, componentWillUnmount and setInterval callback can get executed at same time?

Comment: You may get some kind of performance error in react if the interval is not cleared before unmount. It means if the condition doesn't match and will not clear the time and in that case, it could arise problem.